# Hooking into an event raised by my window service

Tags: c#, events, service

I have a windows service I wrote and I want it to raise an event when a certain condition exists.

I want my Windows form application to receive those events. Is this possible?

This service has to run when all users are logged off, but when they log in and start the app, I want it to begin receiving events from the service.

Comment: How you do this depends on what kind of event you need. Are you looking to just raise a flag all the listeners will be notified of or are you wanting to pass data through the event?

Comment: HI, I just need it to fire a notify event so the win app can refresh itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create a WCF endpoint in the service. Your applications would connect to that and then use a normal event delegate for information handling from the service.

This also will allow multiple clients and also remote clients, if necessary

For very old code there is .NET remoting, but better to update the code to use newer frameworks if possible.

Comment: WCF, yes, .NET Remoting, no. That's a legacy technology which should not be used in new development.

Comment: @JohnSaunders True, should've mentioned that only if using old frameworks. Editing

Comment: WCF is very good for this, and if you are only using a single machine `NetNamedPipeBinding` is likely the best option for your WCF binding to use too.

Answer (score 2):

Your Win App may host WCF service endpoint. Your Win Service will attempt to invoke method Notify of that WCF service resolving to localhost. When Win App is running, Win Service will successfully connect and invoke method Notify.

Comment: It is probably better that the service be the endpoint not the app. The service will not know which endpoints to connect to (each instance will need a uniquely named endpoint).

Comment: Yeah, in that case callback will be required for Notify.